# False positive rate in Bloom Filter

Tags: data-structures, bloom-filter

One quick question regarding Bloom Filter,

If I allocate the size of Bloom filter exactly same as that of number of elements going to be inserted and also using unique hash functions, can I ensure that it won't result in false positive case.

Note that in my case, I know the number of elements going to be inserted well in advance before bloom filter creation

thanks
Prabu

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can create some hash function that does 1:1 mapping. But in that case, there is no point of using Bloom Filter. The whole point of Bloom filter is to save space.

Comment: still we are doing bit level operations per element. So if i need to insert 1024 elements, 1024/8 = 128 bytes alone allocated. am i right ?